# My base64 encoded byte[] stream has extra characters after sent through a http response

Tags: java, pdf, base64

I encode a pdf into a base64 byte[] stream and I want to send it as a http response to the browser. The problem is that the browser fails to load pdf.

I compared the base 64 string which I printed into the IDE console and the one from the browser console. The one from the IDE console is correct and the one from the browser has extra characters.

So, my base64 byte[]stream gets broken somehow when it's sent as a http response ? How do I solve this?

L.e. : The code

```
    FileInputStream inputFileInputStream = null;
    ServletOutputStream outputFileOutputStream = null;

    File exportFile = new File(exportedReport);
    int fileSize = (int) exportFile.length();
    String fullPathToExport = exportFile.getAbsolutePath();
    File fullPathFile = new File(fullPathToExport);

    try {
        // test to see if the path of the file is correct
        System.out.println("The file is located at: "
                + exportFile.getAbsolutePath());

        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(fileSize);
        response.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
        response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + exportedReport +"\"");


        inputFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fullPathFile);
        outputFileOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();

        if (bytesToRead == -1) {
            bytesToRead = (int)fullPathFile.length();
        }
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while((inputFileInputStream != null) && ((bytesRead = inputFileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)){ 

            if (codec.equals("base64")) {
                //outputFileOutputStream.write(Base64.encodeBytes(buffer).getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, bytesToRead);

                outputFileOutputStream.write(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(buffer));

            } else {
                outputFileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
            }
        }
        inputFileInputStream.close();
        outputFileOutputStream.flush();
        outputFileOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: What is the extra character? Can you show an example of the intended output and what you actually get?

Comment: Please add the relevant code. Possible cause of the error: per specification it is required to add the headers before the actual payload.

Comment: I edited the question with the code where I add the header. The browser displays the pdf correctly with the copy pasted base 64 string.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for inflating up the PDF by encoding it base64?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. I need to encode the pdf to base64 in order to send it as a http response to the browser by my servlet.

Comment: *I need to encode the pdf to base64 in order to send it as a http response* - in general you don't need to do that, merely if the connection can only handle 7-bit data.

Comment: Let's say that I need to use base64. How do avoid this problem ?

Comment: Could you complete the relevant section? Just add everything from encoding, headers, writing the stream etc. Furthermore: could you post the additional characters you've mentioned?

Comment: I added the whole code that does the encoding, headers and writing the steam.

Comment: You are setting the content-length header to the unencoded data length. According to RFC2616 you have to set it to the "transfer-length of the message-body".

Comment: Thank you Robert. Your comment solved my issue ! I edited your response too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has one major problem:

You are not sending one base64 encoded data part but many base64 encoded data parts (concatenated). But two or more base64 encoded data parts are not equal to one base64 encoded data part.

Example:

```
base64("This is a test") -> "VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q="
base64("This ")+base64("is a ")+base64("test") -> "VGhpcyA=aXMgYSA=dGVzdA=="
```

You should use the org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream instead of the Base64.encodeBase64() utility method. Read the whole FileInputStream through it and you will get a valid base64 encoded data stream.

Anyway what you are doing is not necessary. You can transfer any 8 bit data via HTTP without further encoding.

Comment: *But two or more base64 encoded data parts are not equal to one base64 encoded data part* ... unless you make sure that the lengths of all (but the final) data parts can be divided by 3. But the OP's code indeed does not seem to guarantee that.